# Using LINQ to SQL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Up till now most of the web apps Ive built have an Oracle database behind them, so when fetching or updating data, Id pass search variables to a class to build the SQL, open a connection and create a DataTable to pass back to the form which I then bind to a gridview - easy stuff.

I'm now using Linq for a SQL Server database.  I can easily build this up and get it working on a button_click event (code below), but if I were to pass the variables to a separate class to do this so that it not running from code-behind, what exactly is it Im returning back to the form?

Hope that makes sense - I'm basically wanting to do whats below but not in code-behind.

```
ASB_DataDataContext adb = new ASB_DataDataContext();
var qryAdb = from asb in adb.Inputts
             select new
             {
                 NRTno = asb.NRT_No,
                 PerpSurname = asb.Allg_Perp_Surname,
                 PerpSteet = asb.Allg_Perp_Street,
                 HouseNo = asb.Allg_Perp_House_No,
                 Complainer = asb.Complainant_Surname,
                 Complainer_Street = asb.Complainant_Street
             };

if (txtCompSurname.Text != "")
    qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.Complainer == txtCompSurname.Text);
if (txtCompStreet.Text != "")
    qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.Complainer_Street == txtCompStreet.Text);
if (txtPerpSurname.Text != "")
    qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.PerpSurname == txtPerpSurname.Text);
if (txtPerpStreet.Text != "")
    qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.PerpSteet == txtPerpStreet.Text);
if (txtNrtNo.Text != "")
    qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.NRTno == Convert.ToInt32(txtNrtNo.Text));


gvResults.DataSource = qryAdb.Select(o => new { o.NRTno, o.PerpSurname, o.PerpSteet, o.HouseNo, o.Complainer, o.Complainer_Street });
gvResults.DataBind();
```

Comment: not in code behind? so as parameters to a stored procedure? You are not bound to Linq2SQL by the way. You can still use `SqlCommand` and use `DataTable`objects to bind to gridviews etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a POCO class for whatever it is you are getting back:

```
public class Person
{
    public NRTNo string {get; set;}
    ....
}
```

Select into this class in your LINQ (note the Person class name after select new):

```
var qryAdb = (from asb in adb.Inputts
                          select new Person
                          {
                              NRTno = asb.NRT_No,
                              PerpSurname = asb.Allg_Perp_Surname,
                              PerpSteet = asb.Allg_Perp_Street,
                              HouseNo = asb.Allg_Perp_House_No,
                              Complainer = asb.Complainant_Surname,
                              Complainer_Street = asb.Complainant_Street
                          });
```

Do what you are already doing with the query:

```
            if (txtCompSurname.Text != "")
                qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.Complainer == txtCompSurname.Text);
            if (txtCompStreet.Text != "")
                qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.Complainer_Street == txtCompStreet.Text);
            if (txtPerpSurname.Text != "")
                qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.PerpSurname == txtPerpSurname.Text);
            if (txtPerpStreet.Text != "")
                qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.PerpSteet == txtPerpStreet.Text);
            if (txtNrtNo.Text != "")
                qryAdb = qryAdb.Where(asb => asb.NRTno == Convert.ToInt32(txtNrtNo.Text));
```

Now return a list of your POCO objects:

```
return qryAdb.ToList<Person>();
```

You can now bind to this in your UI in the same way you currently bind.

Comment: Ahhh...  had tried this earlier - all that I was missing was the .ToList<> - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can't return an anonymous type from that "other class", so you need to create a "real" class for a single return value. Then you can return an `IEnumerable<ReturnClass>` from your method.

You can then bind against that returned value.

Comment: You _can_ return an anonymous type and use it for binding a grid just like with non anonymous types. I would however recommend to create a real DTO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility: use a webform for userinput. send the query to a class (not code behind of the form) and still write sql like you are used to. (only no-oracle syntax) and parse it to objects and return a `List` collection of the object. you can also return a datatable and bind that to the gridview. Hope it helps a bit.

WebForms1.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="go" OnClick="btn_OnClick"/><br/>
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv"></asp:GridView>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
    {
        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        List<Complainer> complainers = cl.SearchBySurname(tb.Text);
        gv.DataSource = complainers;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Class1.cs:

```
public class Class1
{
    internal List<Complainer> SearchBySurname(string p)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Complainers where surname = @sur ");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("sur", p);
        List<Complainer> complainers = new List<Complainer>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconstring"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Complainer c = new Complainer(dr);
                complainers.Add(c);
            }
        }
        return complainers;
    }
}
```

Complainer.cs:

```
public class Complainer
{
    private int _id;

    public Complainer(System.Data.DataRow dr)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        _id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
    }
}
```

**edit**
put the sample project on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7clhlvgdk2gul3/WebApplication2.zip